# importerror numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, numpy

#### 環境

mac os 10.9.5
python 2.7.5
Numpy 1.11.0
gunicorn 19.3.0

#### 困っていること

virtualenvを使ってpythonコードを動かしているのですがpythonコードを更新するたびに`importerror numpy.core.multiarray failed to import` になります....

Numpyとpythonのバージョンが合っていないからだと思い、最初からmacに入っているnumpyを削除したりして一時は正常に動くようになったのですが上記のエラーがまた何度も出るようになってしまいました....

ちなみにpythonインタプリタでimport numpyしても上記のエラーが出ません。エラーが出るのは`gunicorn`起動時です。

上記のエラーはググればかなり例が出てくるのですが解決できずにいます。ざっくりした文章ですが何かわかるかたがいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

---

`gunicorn main:app --log-file=-`
でgunicornを起動しています。
activeを行っても行わなくてもgunicorn起動時に`ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`なってしまいます。。

Answer (score 1):

gunicornからの起動はどういうコマンドやconfigでやっていますか？
activateを行ってからpythonを起動していて問題があるのでしょうか？
そうであれば、activateせずに、activateとおなじディレクトリにあるpythonをフルパスで指定してgunicornから起動するようにしてみてください。